# How will the use of various formats with @font-face affect bandwidth load?

Tags: load, font-face

Using four various formats of my web font (e.g. calculated for me by www.fontsquirrel.com) : True Type / EOT / SVG / WOFF and embedding them via CSS as such:

```css
src: url('../fonts/webfont.eot');
src: local('☺'),
     url('../fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('../fonts/webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
     url('webfont.svg#webfontAXSQe9it') format('svg');
```

... will each Browser load all of the four fonts or just pick the one it likes best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its partly a browser hack
ie will load the ttf and is done

the local (smiley) prevents ie from downloading more
new ff/chrome take the woff and are done
the leftover browsers fall trough downloading them one by one till theres a useable version

also you can test this by creating a script that loggs the request
or just check the server logs

the #webfontAXSQe9it is also a css trick used to prevent certain browsers loading that file